# How to define default ACTION_VIEW intent for specific mime?

Tags: android, android-intent, default, mime-types

I'm trying to find default `Intent` which device is using to support specific mime type, code like:

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    List<ResolveInfo> lri = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo:lri)
    {
        if(Me.DEBUG)
            Log.i(TAG, "Resolved intent="+resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName+
                    ", default="+resolveInfo.isDefault+
                    ", order="+resolveInfo.preferredOrder+
                    ", match="+resolveInfo.match+
                    ", priority="+resolveInfo.priority);
        if(resolveInfo.isDefault)
        {
            intent=pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.resolvePackageName);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeTypes.getMimeTypeString(name));
            break;
        }
    }
    return intent;
```

What's wrong with this code? ResolveInfo never returns default one... Logcat reports always the same, like:

> Resolved intent=com.android.htmlviewer, default=false, order=0,
>   match=6324224, priority=0 Resolved intent=com.sec.print.mobileprint,
>   default=false, order=0, match=6324224, priority=0 Resolved
>   intent=com.qo.android.htc, default=false, order=0, match=6324224,
>   priority=0 Resolved intent=org.coolreader, default=false, order=0,
>   match=6324224, priority=0 Resolved intent=xcxin.filexpert,
>   default=false, order=0, match=6324224, priority=0 Resolved
>   intent=com.opera.browser, default=false, order=0, match=6324224,
>   priority=0 Resolved intent=com.dropbox.android, default=false,
>   order=0, match=6324224, priority=0

Though there's default marked user as "make this the default" checkbox on the chooser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, "default" means the user set a default, by having this `Intent` invoked previously and checking the "make this the default" checkbox on the chooser. If that has not already been done, there is no default.

Comment: Exactly. I'm looking for those which marked user as default! Are there way to find it? In my case there's such default, but I can't find it, logs doesn't show anything!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed there wasn't a default set for this `Intent`. I would have expected your code to work for that case. Regardless, pepending on your use case, either use `getPreferredActivities()` or `resolveActivity()`, both on `PackageManager`.